# Accurate distance sensor via soft materials

Tags: sensors

I'm trying to find a sensor that can measure distance between sensor and some sort of detectable material (metal or small wireless chip) size of no more than a penny.
It should be able to measure through fabric as thick as (~40cm) with max distance of 2 meters and accuracy 0.3%.
What are my option if any?

Comment: https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/communications/article/21800581/whats-the-difference-between-measuring-location-by-uwb-wifi-and-bluetooth you may find this interesting? The suggestion of accuracy to 5-10cm would be 0.25-0.5% over your full scale